# I'm not able to make a post request using FormGroup Angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, typescript

I'm new to angular, I am not able to make a post request using formGroup. The body is being sent for all the fields that I have however, there is an error 400 (bad request) due to the following error: {"status":"error","errors":{"message":"A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations."}}, I kind of understand what the error is about but I don't understand what's wrong with my code. thanks in advance

register.model.ts

```
export class User{
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
    UserName: string;
    Email: string;
    Password: string;
}
```

register.service.ts

```
RegisterUser(user: User){
return this.http.post('url', user);
```

}

register.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">First Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" formControlName="FirstName" class="form-control"
        placeholder="First Name" ngModel>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" formControlName="LastName" class="form-control"
        id="LastName" placeholder="LastName" ngModel>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="UserName" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" formControlName="UserName" class="form-control"
        placeholder="User Name" ngModel>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="email" formControlName="Email" class="form-control"
        placeholder="example@example.com" ngModel>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="password" formControlName="Password"  class="form-control"
        placeholder="*********" ngModel>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <p class="text-center">Already have an account? <span>
      <button (click)="goToSignIn();" class="unstyled-button">Sign In.</button>
    </span></p>

  <button type="submit" class="button button4">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

register.component.ts

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

user: User;
registerForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private router: Router, private userService: RegisterService, private toastr: 
          ToastrService, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.registerForm = this.fb.group({
    FirstName: ['', Validators.required],
    LastName: ['', Validators.required],
    UserName: ['', Validators.required],
    Email: ['', Validators.required],
    Password: ['', Validators.required],
  })
}


onSubmit(){
  return this.userService.RegisterUser(this.registerForm.value).subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.toastr.success('User Registered Successfully');
  }, error => {
    this.toastr.error('Registeration Failed');
  })
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a javascript error that you are having the problem with. This is an error comming from Entity Framework.

Your DBContext is being used by two threads at the same time. It could be that it is used by two threads in the same request.

Check that your DBContext is not declared static for some reason.

You need to share your api code in order for us to debug your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response, actually it was working previously when I wasn't using formGroup, I didn't change anything in my code except that I just removed the ngModel and used formGroup

Comment: Have you compared the payload from your console with those two approaches? My guess is that you send different data that affects the execution in your backend code. Since we haven't got both, then we can't do it for you. If you post the payloads, then we can make assumption as of why

Comment: The reason that I'm sure there is nothing wrong with api's payload is that when I take the data from the console and paste it Postman, everything works

Comment: Revert your code to ngModel and check again side by side what you were sending. Not only payload but headers too. My thinking is that some filter or data is not being sent correctly so something breaks in your backend. Then you are writing something in your database (maybe error) using the same db context and fail. If I were you I would add a breakpoint in my api code and check what happens there.

Comment: okay, this has been sorted out, I did what you said and I found out that the problem was that I couldn't register a user while I'm logged in, so I had to clear the session to be able to register a new user

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
registerUser(user) : Observable<any> {
return this.http.post<any>('url', JSON.stringify(user), this.httpOptions).pipe(
    tap((user) => console.log(`user sent : ${JSON.stringify(user)}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
```

};

the httpOptions are like this:

```
httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})
```

};

for catch error:

```
handleError(error) {
let errorMessage = '';
if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
// Get client-side error
errorMessage = error.error.message;
} else {
// Get server-side error
errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
}
window.alert(errorMessage);
return throwError(errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, actuallty I'm still getting the same error, btw it was working when I wasn't using the formGroup, I was using the ngModel, however, when I tried using the formGroup it came up with this error